# Is this proof of almost sure convergence correct

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence of random variables $X_i$ such that $P[X_n = 1 ] = \frac{1}{n}$ and $P[X_n = 0 ] = 1 -\frac{1}{n}$.

We can see that this sequence $X_i$ converges in probablity to the sequence $X = 0$  because $P[|X_n - 0| > \epsilon] = P[X_i = 1] = \frac{1}{n} $ and hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} P[|X_n - 0| > \epsilon]  = 0$

***My attempt at almost sure convergence:***

We have to prove/disprove that $P[\lim_{n \to \infty}  X_n  = 0] = 1$. One way to look at this is: We have a sequence of random variables $X_n(\omega)$ being generated by the Bernoulli distribution whose PMF is ${(\frac{1}{n})}^{\omega}{(\frac{n-1}{n})}^{1-\omega}$ where $\omega$ can take values {0,1}.

As $n \to \infty$, the chance of observing the 1's will reduce with n. However, we cannot for sure that we will always observe $X_n = 0$, no matter how large the n is. We can say, for sure, we will always observe $X_n = 0$ only if $n = \infty$, otherwise there is always +ve chance that we can observe 1's.  Hence the probability of the event $[\lim_{n \to \infty}  X_n  = 0]$ is zero. Hence, the above sequence of random variables does not almost surely converge to $0$.

Is this argument correct? Are there more elegant arguments either to disprove or prove the almost sure convergence?

Comment: The proof is wrong since both almost sure divergence and almost sure convergence may occur. Additionally, the statement that $X_n = 0$ only if $n = \infty$ is absurd since there is no $X_\infty$ in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments your argument is not valid. This sequence need not converge almost surely and, if $\{X_n\}$ is independent, then  it does not converge almost surely. This is because $\sum P\{X_n >\frac 1 2 \} =\sum \frac 1 n =\infty$. Apply Borel -Cantelli Lemma to conclude that $\{X_n\}$ converges to $0$ with probability $0$!.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how the Borel-Cantelli lemma is used here?

Comment: If $\{A_n\}$ is an independent sequence of events such that $\sum P(A_n) =\infty$ then infinitely many of the events occur with probability $1$. This is the second part of Borel-Cantelli Lemma (the first part dealing with the case when the sum is finite). In our case this means that $X_n >\frac 1 2$ for infinitely many values of  $n$, with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank -  you . !